# Save HTML Form data into a File using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a code to extract some form data from a HTML file and save them in a file using Javascript.

Example: Name, Password and email should be stored in a file (text or XML) so that i can use it later.

How can i do it? i'm new to JavaScript !!!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found what to do. in Javascript there is a class called widget in which you can store pre-defined keys such as username, password, unique key etc etc ....

Syntax:

```
widget.setPreferenceForKey(stringValue,stringKey);

//example
widget.setPreferenceForKey('foo','username');
```

you can retrieve these using the same class and assigning the value to a var,

```
widget.PreferenceForKey(stringKey);

//example
var user = widget.PreferenceForKey('username');
```

Important: you need the WRT extension installed for this to work

hope this will help .....

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this in a browser? If so, which? None of the released (non early beta) browsers have the W3c File Writer spec implemented yet - link at http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/

Your best (only) bet is to just store the data into local storage/web storage

Comment: Hello, this is a local app written for a nokia phone using the Nokia WRT web development technology.